# How to optimize this sqlrq? Is it proper? How do better?

Tags: mysql, optimization, left-join, inner-join

Thank you for your attention.
All night long trying my best but no result.
I`m quite new to mySQL.

---

Please tell me 
is it properly constructed and optimized:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    (`tbl_projects` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_files` 
    ON ((`file_isforType` = 1) AND `file_isforID`=`proj_uid`) )
INNER JOIN `tbl_users` 
    ON `proj_InitiatorUsrID` = `usr_UID` )
ORDER BY `file_uid` DESC LIMIT 0 , 15
```

---

I've used EXPLAIN on it
and found that it is not using any key for the first table `table_projects`.

i've put screenshot there =

[image]

---

The idea of database is next.
Any user can publish any amount of projects and 
every project may have its pictures (0..x)

project MAY HAVE also an attached file. may have 1 or some or may not have.

---

joint is next:
project innerjoin user  leftjoin files

What I`m getting by this rq:

```
proj1 | user1 | photo1
proj1 | user1 | photo2
proj1 | user1 | photo3

proj2 | user1 | photo4
proj2 | user1 | photo5

proj3 | user2 | photo6

proj4 | user1 | null

proj5 | user1 | photo7
proj5 | user1 | photo8
proj6 | user2 | null
```

so going one-by-one from top to bottom my php script
forms in html list of projects.
some has no photos. some has one. some has 2,3,4..etc.

```
proj1 - user1 - 3 photos
proj2 - user1 - 2 photos
proj3 - user2 - 1 photo
proj4 - user1 -  no photos
proj5 - user1 - 2 photos
etc
```

table_files is build in next logic:

```
file_uid | file_ownerID | file_isforType| file_isforID
file_uid PRIMARY AI
file_ownerID  reference to PRIMARY at table_users
file_isforType- smallint 1..9
indicates type of THING which this file was attached to.
 eg
1 = _TheProject as project photo
2 = _TheUserProfile as users photo
3 = _TheMessage as attachment

file_ResourceID - unique id of that very thing, whose type specified in file_isforType.
```

eg

```
if (file_isWhatfor=_TheProject) AND (file_ResourceID=3)    ->> to the proj#3
if (file_isWhatfor=_TheUserProfile) AND (file_ResourceID=3)    ->> to the user#3
if (file_isWhatfor=_TheMessage) AND (file_ResourceID=3)    ->> to the msg#3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Using GROUP BY on the proj and use column, and GROUP_CONCAT() on the photo column would greatly reduce the number of rows, and make the PHP code simpler.

Comment: We can't judge the query without knowing which table each column is in.  Please qualify the columns by what table they come from.

Comment: I see `LIMIT 0, 15` -- will you be "paginating"?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible for us to know if this is "optimised" because that requires knowing more than you have told us. More on that later.

While MySQL does permit the use of backticks for identities, it is not mandatory that you use then UNLESS an identity contains a space or is a reserved word. What is necessary is to prefix column names with their table name OR use table aliases instead. This is strongly advised (i.e. "best practice") so that you always know which table a column comes from. Note I have had to GUESS which table alias to use in all the joins below, they may need correction.

```
SELECT 
       *
FROM   tbl_projects AS p
LEFT JOIN tbl_files AS f ON p.proj_uid = f.file_isforID AND f.file_isforType = 1
INNER JOIN tbl_users AS u ON p.proj_InitiatorUsrID = u.usr_UID
ORDER BY f.file_uid DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Please also note that all the parentheses you used are completely redundant and can safely be removed.

To "optimise" further I suggest you do NOT use `select *`. Specify the columns you need, this can improve speed of result transmission, but not necessarily have any measurable impact on query execution. Beyond that you need to have indexes on all columns involved in all the joins, and you can study if indexes are missing by using an `explain plan`. See [8.8.1 Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html)

If there is a missing index consider adding it to the table that the explain identifies.

Comment: concerning 

"  "best practice")  of cource you have noticed that every field name has a prefix of its parent table and is unique.  is it ok?

Comment: Yes. It is "OK". However if you use self joins or need to have multiple joins to a table that column naming convention is no longer a solution.  It remains strongly advised, even with your column naming convention.